# Sum of real numbers equal to integer number

Tags: arithmetic, integers, natural-numbers

Let $t_1, t_2, ..., t_n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$, $t = \sum_{i=1}^n t_i$, and $s \in \{n,n+1, ..., t\}$. Does an integer function $f: \mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ such that
$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}f\left(s \cdot\dfrac{t_i}{t}\right) = s$ exist?

Comment: Do you want s on both sides?

Comment: @martycohen Yes. It is equivalent to the summation being equal to 1.

Comment: @lulu, you are right. I changed the expression such that s is now considered when f is evaluated. It seems to me that now the equality is possible in some cases, e.g., taking f as a rounding function. However, in some case rounding fails.

Comment: the problem still isn't clear, at least not to me.  Is there meant to be a single $f$ that works in all situations or is $f$ chosen specifically to work with the given data?  In any case, you still require $s≥n$.

Comment: @lulu, The $s$ range was wrong;  I fixed it. Also, $f$ should work in all situations.